aks internal load balancer not working properly
I try to deploy AKS with internal load balancer enabled.
Internal load balancer is deployed by istio ingress gateway.
profile.yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: istio-controlplane
spec:
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
  components:
    egressGateways:
    - name: istio-egressgateway
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 40Mi
    ingressGateways:
    - name: istio-ingressgateway
      enabled: true
      k8s:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 40Mi
        serviceAnnotations:
          service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
        service:
          type: LoadBalancer
          loadBalancerIP: 10.1.2.254
          ports:
            - port: 5000
              targetPort: 5000
              name: store-front
            - port: 5001
              targetPort: 5001
              name: web-service
    pilot:
      k8s:
        env:
          - name: PILOT_TRACE_SAMPLING
            value: "100"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 100Mi
  values:
    global:
      proxy:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 40Mi
    pilot:
      autoscaleEnabled: false
    gateways:
      istio-egressgateway:
        autoscaleEnabled: false
      istio-ingressgateway:
        autoscaleEnabled: false

gateway.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: app-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 5000
      name: sample
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - "*"
  - port:
      number: 5001
      name: app
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: store-front
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /sample
    route:
    - destination:
        host: store-front.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5000
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: web-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /app
    route:
    - destination:
        host: web-service.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5001

When I tried to connect to http://10.1.2.254/app or http://10.1.2.254/sample from VM via VNet peering, it didn't work.
So I deployed a test pod and tried to curl , it didn't work either.
It seems VirtualService is not working properly.
Is there any cause about it?
kubectl version: v1.30.0
istioctl version: 1.22.3

It's possible that the VirtualService is not working properly. You can check the logs of the Istio ingress gateway pod to see if there are any errors related to the VirtualService. To set up an AKS cluster with Istio and an internal load balancer, follow these steps-
verify the versions

you can even enable istio from aks portal when setting up the cluster


Istio pods are running, the next step is to configure the Istio Ingress Gateway with an internal load balancer
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: aks-istio-system
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: http2
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      name: https
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      name: store-front
    - port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
      name: web-service



next we will deploy your sample applications store-front.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: store-front
  labels:
    app: store-front
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: store-front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: store-front
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: store-front
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: store-front
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
  selector:
    app: store-front

We will also have to create a deployment YAML for Web Service
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-service
  labels:
    app: web-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web-service
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5001
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5001
  selector:
    app: web-service


next we need to configure Istio gateway and virtual services
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: app-gateway
  namespace: aks-istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 5000
      name: sample
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      number: 5001
      name: app
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: store-front
  namespace: aks-istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /sample
    route:
    - destination:
        host: store-front.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5000
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: web-service
  namespace: aks-istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /app
    route:
    - destination:
        host: web-service.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5001


If the Ingress Gateway is not deployed, create a deployment for it and ensure it correctly mounts the root CA certificate. If you don't have an external certificate, you can create a self-signed one and create a secret

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: aks-istio-system
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
      istio: ingressgateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: istio-ingressgateway
        istio: ingressgateway
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: istio-proxy
        image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.22.3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 5000
        - containerPort: 5001
        args:
        - proxy
        - router
        - --domain
        - $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        - --log_output_level=default:info
        - --drainDuration
        - 45s
        - --parentShutdownDuration
        - 60s
        - --connectTimeout
        - 10s
        - --serviceCluster
        - istio-ingressgateway
        - --zipkinAddress
        - $(ZIPKIN)
        - --proxyLogLevel=warning
        - --proxyComponentLogLevel=misc:error
        - --dnsRefreshRate=300s
        - --statusPort
        - "15020"
        - --trust-domain=cluster.local
        - --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
        - MUTUAL_TLS
        - --discoveryAddress
        - istiod.aks-istio-system.svc:15012
        - --proxyAdminPort
        - "15000"
        - --concurrency
        - "2"
        - --controlPlaneBootstrap=true
        env:
        - name: JWT_POLICY
          value: third-party-jwt
        - name: PILOT_CERT_PROVIDER
          value: istiod
        - name: CA_ADDR
          value: istiod.aks-istio-system.svc:15012
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: INSTANCE_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: HOST_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
        - name: CANONICAL_SERVICE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.labels['service.istio.io/canonical-name']
        - name: CANONICAL_REVISION
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.labels['service.istio.io/canonical-revision']
        - name: SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
        volumeMounts:
        - name: istio-ingressgateway-certs
          mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs
          readOnly: true
        - name: istio-certs
          mountPath: /etc/certs
          readOnly: true
        - name: istio-root-ca
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/istio
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway-certs
        secret:
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-certs
          optional: true
      - name: istio-certs
        secret:
          secretName: istio.istio-system
      - name: istio-root-ca
        secret:
          secretName: istio.istio-system

Verify the Pod Status

Get the Internal Load Balancer IP

Test the Services (if you are doing this from inside a VM then as you said it has to be in same vnet i.e. got to do vnet peering )
Few additional checks I would suggest-
Validate DNS resolution.
kubectl run -i --tty --rm dnsutils --image=gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/dnsutils:1.3 --restart=Never -- nslookup store-front.default.svc.cluster.local
kubectl run -i --tty --rm dnsutils --image=gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/dnsutils:1.3 --restart=Never -- nslookup web-service.default.svc.cluster.local


Check for any NetworkPolicies blocking kubectl get networkpolicy -A
References:

Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) external or internal ingresses for Istio service mesh add-on deployment
Troubleshoot network problems in AKS clusters


thanks!!
I checked the log of ingress gateway and nothing about connection was recorded.
maybe virtualservice is not working properly.

@Arko
I checked every resource was deployed successfully.
enter image description here
nslookup succeeded from my test pod.
enter image description here
But nothing about connection was recorded on the log of ingress gateway pod.
enter image description here
So, it seems virtualservice is not working properly.
